# how to access items from datalist

Tags: asp.net

How to access to Label5 from behind page file(default.aspx.cs)?

```
         <ItemTemplate>

             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="nav_url_odg" runat="server"><%# Eval("user") %></asp:HyperLink> <span class="odgovorio">je odgovorio:</span><br />
       <div>
           <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></div>
    </div>
    <br /></div> </div>
      </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an OnItemDataBound event handler to your markup for the DataList:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" OnItemDataBound="datalist_ItemDataBound">
```

Then in your code behind you can to check the item type, and find the label control by its id:

```
    void datalist_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            Label label5 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("label5");
            // now you have access for each bound row
        }
    }
```