# Accessing Datalist Bound Template label Control on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Thank you for taking time to read my query. I have searched everywhere for 2 days now and still I can't find anyone with a similar issue to mine. I have a asp.net project that has a master page. On the master page there is a content placeholder control. I have a child page derived from the master page. On the child page I have added a datalist control that is bound to an Sqldatasource being filled by a stored procedure. The datalist control has a label item template.

I am trying to access the label using this from code behind:

```
 Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim myLabel As Label = CType(DataList1.FindControl("UnitPriceLabel"), Label)
        myLabel.Text = "new text"

    End If
End Sub
```

I get an object reference not set to instance of object error because "myLabel" comes through with nothing.

I have tried code from here:

[accessing controls in datalist headertemplate from codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933540/accessing-controls-in-datalist-headertemplate-from-codebehind)

[Accessing asp.net controls of datalist in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266138/accessing-asp-net-controls-of-datalist-in-codebehind)

[Define Datalist HeaderTemplate in c# from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660054/define-datalist-headertemplate-in-c-sharp-from-code-behind)

[how to access items from datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749890/how-to-access-items-from-datalist)

I think it has something to do with the contentplaceholder on the master page control but I just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Dim myLabel As Label = CType(DataList1.FindControl("UnitPriceLabel"), Label)
```

to this:

```
Dim myLabel As Label = CType(e.Item.FindControl("UnitPriceLabel"), Label)
```

You could even do this in one line if you wanted:

```
DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("UnitPriceLabel"), Label).Text = "new text"
```

However, personnaly I would only do this If I needed to access the label once and not multiple times.

Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitemeventargs.aspx) from Microsoft for more info.

Comment: If you ever need to use a Repeater control, the process is very much the same. Glad to help.